# How to get list of files with not having search string

Tags: linux, find, aix

I have a requirement to display all files in a directory which doesn't have `CountOfFilesTransmitted=0` string in them.

If I give below command it gives only those files which has `CountOfFilesTransmitted=1`

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "CountOfFilesTransmitted=1"
```

Gives: 1.log, 2.log, 10.log

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "CountOfFilesTransmitted=1" -- gives 3.log, 7.log
```

There are logs in that directory with 0 to 100 files Transmitted I have to give 101 entries. Is there a way to get filenames which have non zero?

something like "`find . -type f | xargs grep -l "CountOfFilesTransmitted!=0`" which should return all files which doesn't have "`CountOfFilesTransmitted=0`" string.

Answer (score 2):

This Answer will only work IF a file does not **also** contain the pattern of `CountOfFilesTransmitted=0` assuming that the goal OP has is to show to files that contain that pattern at all.

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -le "CountOfFilesTransmitted=[1-9]"
```

using `-e` to allow for regex

Comment: @don_crissti Hmm... Very valid, Hadn't considered that as a possible outcome.. And yes, Just Did a test of the other question's answer, Definitely meets OP's needs.... Assuming of course his needs are as I understand them.

Comment: Hi Gravy, Appreciate your reply!   But there are few files with 100, 101 as well. If I use [1-1000]. It also finds 0 right?

Comment: @kumar2008 The only question would be if a file might have both `0` and another one. This answer will find `100`, `101`, `1000`, `10000`. Essentially, matching that the first digit after `CountOfFilesTransmitted` is not `0`, So it will find anything that isn't just `0`, on the other hand it will not find `01` if you have that formatting it will fail.

Comment: @kumar2008 let me know if that doesn't work for you and i'll work on another answer :) Assuming there isn't a correct answer in the other question

Comment: Hi Gravy, sorry for late reply. had a rough day. I have tested and above command also brings files which has CountOfFilesTransmitted=0 when given [1-1000]

Comment: @kumar2008 Are those files that contain `CountOfFilesTransmitted=0` AND `CountOfFilesTransmitted=<someother number>` that is something i haven't been sure on your question, are there multiple lines that have countoffiles, and you want files that don't contain 0 at all?

Comment: Gravy, yes there are multiple lines. In every file there will be CountOfFilesTransmitted=0 for sure initially as it initializes. As transmission is done. there is another entry. for example. If it transmits 3 files then CountOfFilesTransmitted=3. if it transmits 100 files then CountOfFilesTransmitted=100. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: @kumar2008 I'm a bit confused now. If all files contain a starting point of `0` in them, then A) What results are you actually looking for? and B) What is not working about the solution I wrote out above? Any more explanation would help.

Comment: In the solution you gave.  if I give "find . -type f | xargs grep -le "CountOfFilesTransmitted=[1-100]" It is also pulling CountOfFilesTransmitted=0 Which apparently in all the files. And displaying all files basically.

Comment: ok let me explain what I am looking. I have a script which transmits files. For each run I am creating a log file which basically has the entry giving how many files transmitted in that run. There will be "CountOfFilesTransmitted=0" entry in all the logs. If there are any files transmitted I will increment this counter and end of the log will reflect that number. example: "CountOfFilesTransmitted=10". Find command should only give those log files in which CountOfFilesTransmitted is greater than 0. Hope I am clear. Thanks!